# Creating a selector pointing to raw text

Tags: jquery, sizzle

Following up on https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/886#issuecomment-46210448, I'm trying to return a jQuery selector containing raw text (no HTML tags), but if I do `$("Error: something has gone wrong")` I get:

```
Uncaught object jquery.js:1437
Sizzle.error jquery.js:1437
Sizzle.tokenize jquery.js:2051
Sizzle.select jquery.js:2452
Sizzle jquery.js:843
jQuery.fn.extend.find jquery.js:2668
jQuery.fn.init jquery.js:2776
jQuery jquery.js:76
$.fn.form.settings.templates.error Forms.js:31
$.fn.form.$allModules.each.module.add.errors semantic.js:1638
$.fn.form.$allModules.each.module.invoke semantic.js:1897
(anonymous function) semantic.js:1918
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:375
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:139
$.fn.form semantic.js:1375
```

Wrapping the text in a `<span>` makes the exception go away, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jQuery function with a raw non-HTML string doesn't make sense.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

According to this documentation, the `jQuery()` function parses HTML, and not XML, and by extension not even raw text.

If you need to append some raw text to an element use the `.text()` method.

example:

```
$('.someClass').text('Error: Message');
```

Comment: I understand, but have you read what jlukic is doing in https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/886#issuecomment-46210448? Does it make sense to return `$(html)` in this context?

Comment: As i mentioned, the jQuery function parses valid HTML strings. and even more so if you're using jQuery 1.9 and up.
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring